Highcharts.stockChart is not loading in javescript
chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
chart: {
animation: false,
backgroundColor: '#A9CDDD',
events: {
load: function () {
                        chart = this; // `this` is the reference to the chart
                        requestData();
                    }
                }
            },


Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue? The requestData() method in your code snippet doesn't say much about how you actually request the data and why it's not working. You can start by editing this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fnzx7d6k/
